# React hooks update child when parent state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have hook in parent component passed down along with setState, when I update parent via child it should re-render both, but it doesnt.

```
    // Parent
    const [chosenArticles, setChosenArticles] = React.useState<number[]>([])
    ...
    <ChooseArticles
      setChosenArticles={setChosenArticles}
      chosenArticles={chosenArticles}
     />
    // Child
    export default (props: Props) => {
  const { item, setChosenArticles, chosenArticles } = props
  const checkItem = (articleId: number, check: boolean) => {
    let newArr: number[] = props.chosenArticles
    if (!check) {
      newArr.push(articleId)
    } else {
      newArr = newArr.filter(item => item !== articleId)
    }
    setChosenArticles([...newArr])
  }
  return (
    <ChildComp>
      <ChildTopText>Choose Articles</ChildTopText>
      <ChildInner>
        {item.sub.map((sub: any, i: number) => {
          return (
            <Sub key={i}>
              <ArticleGroup>{sub.name}</ArticleGroup>
              {sub.cats.map((cat: any, i: number) => {
                const isChecked =
                  chosenArticles.filter(c => c === cat.id).length > 0
                    ? true
                    : false
                return (
                  <SubItem key={cat.id}>
                    <CheckBox
                      onPress={() => checkItem(cat.id, isChecked)}
                      checked={isChecked}
                    />
                    <SubName>{cat.name}</SubName>
                  </SubItem>
                )
              })}
            </Sub>
          )
        })}
      </ChildInner>
    </ChildComp>
  )
}
```

Shouldnt this work? The childcomponent gets updated with correct values when I mount it manually again.

I use the state value later to tick a checkbox in the childcomponent.

Comment: Could you share all the Component structure, the Child at least?

Comment: Added jsx from childcomp aswell

Comment: Is it updating the state correctly? Which is the component that doesn't re-render, parent or children?

Comment: Hi, sorry for no update here, I made a big oopsie, using context when I noticed that the parent that calls this is above in the react-tree, hence this is a nonissue.Thank you anyway!